# Как полностью остановить функцию с циклом? JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Имею функцию, эта функция выполняется по нажатию кнопки, затем в функции срабатывает цикл, в цикле есть setTimeout с функцией замыкания. Вопрос, как по нажатию другой кнопки, сделать так чтобы функция с циклом полностью останавливалась/прерывалась?

Comment: Стоит добавить в вопрос имеющийся код. Сам цикл прервать никак нельзя по нажатию кнопки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запоминать значения, возвращаемые вызовами `setTimeout`, и вызывать для тех из них, что еще не отработали, `clearTimeout`.

---

При чем здесь "функция замыкания" - неясно.